# Ciclo for each duplica las columnas de tabla boostrap

Tags: php, html, mysql, bootstrap, codeigniter

actualemnte estoy realizando una consulta a base de datos y trayndo los datos a una tabla de bootstrap, para esto estoy utilizando el Framework Codeigniter, por lo que ya tengo, los modelo, controladores y las vistas, todo funciona bien, en el listado me aparecen los datos de la tabla, sinb embargo aunque las etiqueta  estan bien, en las etiquetas  se agrega una columna por cada valor que se llema de la base de datos, es decir, llama un valor y el siguiente  queda en blanco, llama a otra valor y el siguiente  queda en blanco. Subire una imagen y el código de la vista, esperando ser un poco más clara y espero que alguno me  pueda ayudar

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="box">
   <div class="box-header with-border">
    <div class="left">
     <h3 class="box-title"><?php echo trans('solicitud_verificacion'); ?></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
     <a href="<?php echo admin_url(); ?>add-category" class="btn btn-success btn-add-new">
      <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo trans('add_solicitud-verificacion'); ?>
     </a>
    </div>
   </div><!-- /.box-header -->

   <!-- include message block -->
   <div class="col-sm-12">
    <?php $this->load->view('admin/includes/_messages'); ?>
   </div>

   <div class="box-body">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="table-responsive">
       <table class="table table-bordered table-striped dataTable" id="cs_datatable" role="grid"
           aria-describedby="example1_info">
        <thead>
        <tr role="row">
         <th width="20"><?php echo trans('id'); ?></th>
         <th><?php echo trans('user'); ?></th>
         <th><?php echo trans('tipo_tienda'); ?></th>
         <th><?php echo trans('fecha_resolucion'); ?></th>
         <th><?php echo trans('estado'); ?></th>
         <th><?php echo trans('fecha_creacion'); ?></th>
         <th class="th-options"><?php echo trans('options'); ?></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        <?php foreach ($solicitud_verificacion as $item) : if (!empty($item)):?>
         
          <tr>
           <td scope="row"><?php echo $item->id_solicitud ?></th>
           <td><?php echo $item->usuario ?><td>
           <td><?php echo $item->tipo_tienda ?><td>
           <td><?php echo $item->fecha_resolucion ?><td>
           <td><?php echo $item->estado ?><td>
           <td><?php echo $item->fecha_creacion ?><td>
          
           <td>
            <div class="dropdown">
             <button class="btn bg-purple dropdown-toggle btn-select-option"
               type="button"
               data-toggle="dropdown"><?php echo trans('select_option'); ?>
              <span class="caret"></span>
             </button>
             <ul class="dropdown-menu options-dropdown">
              <li>
               <a href="<?php echo admin_url(); ?>update-solicitud_verificacion/<?php echo html_escape($item->id_solicitud); ?>"><i class="fa fa-edit option-icon"></i><?php echo trans('edit'); ?></a>
              </li>
              <li>
               <a href="<?php echo admin_url(); ?>update-solicitud_verificacion/<?php echo html_escape($item->id_solicitud); ?>"><i class="fa fa-edit option-icon"></i><?php echo trans('delete'); ?></a>
              </li>
             </ul>
            </div>
           </td>
          </tr>

         <?php endif;
         endforeach; ?>

        </tbody>
       </table>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div><!-- /.box-body -->
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Revisa bien tu código. Por ejemplo, ¿qué hace el `</th>` ahí al final: `<td scope="row"><?php echo $item->id_solicitud ?></th>` Luego, ¿intentas meter un botón y una lista dentro de la misma celda? Me refiero al bloque en `<div class="dropdown">`, no es nada claro lo que ahí ocurre.

Comment: Agradezco tu comentario y tienes razón el </th> al final era un error, sin embargo esto no mejoro la situación. Respecto al Dropdown, es el boton que despliega la lista de opciones a ejecutar, en el registro (Editar, eliminar); la cual funciona bien. También he probado anulando este botón, por si en algo ocasionan el error, pero aunque deja de aparecer, continua el error.

Comment: Hice una prueba ingresando desde el código los valores en <td></td> y el listado funciona perfectamente, lo que me deja entrever que el problema podria estar en el ciclo foreach que llama los datos de la tabla, si pudieras echarle un vistazo te lo agradeceria.

Comment: Dentro del `foreach` pon esto: `var_dump($item);` va a imprimir por cada fila el contenido de cada item, copia y pega ese resultado y agrégalo a la pregunta pulsando en [edit]. Si son muchas filas pon solamente una parte de esa salida para analizarla. Puede ser que dentro del mismo contenido que hay en `$item` vengan datos con `<td></td>`

Answer (score 0):

gracias por su colaboración he intentado las sugerencias que me hicieron y continuaba presentado el error.. y despues de repasar muchas veces el código he visto que las etiqueta del , no tenia el baselash (/) al final, solo lo tenia la primra columna y esto soluciono el problema. Nuevamente gracias por su colaboración.